# Updating Table In Partial View

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Goal: Attempting to create a feature where a table is updated with added rows from the database.

I'm running into an issue with how the views are formatted, my knowledge with javascript and MVC isn't strong enough to know which direction to go.

I have the main view, and from there I load in three partialViews separately via an ajax call which populates the div with the defined ID

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div id="preTestSteps">

    </div>

    <div id="mainTestSteps">

    </div>

    <div id="postTestSteps"></div>
</div>
```

With the following function that loads these partial views;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var testSuiteExecutionId = @(Model.TestSuiteExecutionId);
    var testSuiteId = @(Model.TestSuiteId);

    loadTestStepResultsPartialView(testSuiteExecutionId, testSuiteId, 1, "preTestSteps");
    loadTestStepResultsPartialView(testSuiteExecutionId, testSuiteId, 0, "mainTestSteps");
    loadTestStepResultsPartialView(testSuiteExecutionId, testSuiteId, 2, "postTestSteps");

});


function loadTestStepResultsPartialView( testSuiteExecutionId, testSuiteId, testStepType, divId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("DetailsTestStepResults", "TestSuiteExecutions")',
        data: { 'testSuiteExecutionId': testSuiteExecutionId, 'testSuiteId': testSuiteId, 'testStepType': testStepType },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#" + divId).html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

This is working as intended.

Within these partial views, the model for the view is a list of view models, these view models are iterated over with the list of logs defined within them.

Partial View loaded from main view;

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    @foreach (var testStep in Model)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h5 style="background-color: beige; padding: 5px">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => testStep.TestStepName)
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
                @Html.Partial("~/Views/TestSuiteExecutions/TestStepLogsPartialView.cshtml", testStep.TestStepLogs)
        </div>

        <div>
                @Html.Partial("~/Views/TestSuiteExecutions/TestStepLogsPartialView.cshtml", testStep.VerificationLogs)
            <div style="padding-bottom: 25px" class="row"></div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

This is where things start breaking down. The partial views this partial view loads contain the logs and the table.

Log Partial View

```
@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
    var accordianStepItemName = "accordianStep" + Model[0].TestStepId + Model[0].MessageType;
    var collapseStepItemName = "collapseStep" + Model[0].TestStepId + Model[0].MessageType;

    <!--TODO: Use PartialViews-->
    <div class="row">
        <div id="accordion" role="tablist" style="margin-left: 30px" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div id="transparent-card" class="card" style="border-color: white;">

                <h6 class="mb-0">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#@accordianStepItemName" href="#@collapseStepItemName" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="@collapseStepItemName">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                        @(Model[0].MessageType == false ? Html.Raw("Verification Log") : Html.Raw("Execution Log"))
                    </a>
                </h6>

                <div id="@collapseStepItemName" class="collapse col-sm-12" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <table class="table" id="logTable_@Model[0].TestStepId@Model[0].MessageType">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="5%"></th>
                                <th width="20% !important">Time</th>
                                <th width="75%">Message</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (var logEntry in Model)
                                {
                                    <tr id="tableRow_@logEntry.TestStepId@logEntry.MessageType">
                                        <td><img width="20" height="20" src="~/Content/Images/@HtmlUtilities.GetTestSuiteExecutionIconName(logEntry.LogType)" /></td>
                                        <td><i>@logEntry.TimeStamp</i></td>
                                        <td><i>@Html.Raw(HtmlUtilities.GetHtmlFormattedString(logEntry.Message))</i></td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I'm attempting to write a javascrtipt method that will call an ajax call to bring up new log models in a list, and then add new rows to the table, but I'm running into two issues.

1) How do I pass the partial views table id's to the javascript function to execute the update? If I don't have the unique ID's (because this is looped and it needs unique Id's based on what I'm trying to update) then I can't even find the element to attach the new rows to in the script

2) How do I even attach to the table? I've attempted to use static data, but in attempting to access the table within the partial view to just prove I can actually add rows, I get 'getElementsByTagName' is null error in the debug menu.

Is what I'm attempting even possible with the current layout of the view(s)? Would it be better served to simply use one view model and put all of this logic on a single page to make the javascript easier to handle/actually function?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but I can say that ids must be unique to the document, so ids like "accordion" and "transparent-card" should likely be replaced with either classes or `data-id` attributes. Seems like if you want to refresh a table, you'd just call `loadTestStepResultsPartialView` with the appropriate values and it would update the element associated with the table.

Comment: The goal is to update the table(s) without refreshing the entire partial view, to make it so you can have the table tab open under the TestStep and see logs appear as the script fetches new logs from the database, which are then added as new rows to the table.

That way there isn't a "flicker" or any interruption in appearance to the viewer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following:

1. Create a partial view for row.
2. Segregate tables with some unique filters may be the css class.
3. Use those id to append rows.